# query using wpdb in wordpress gets me no result

Tags: wpdb, sql

I get no result unless i cut the string title to "Gocomma 10W QI Wireless Fast Charger Car Mount Holder " ...

```
   $title1="Gocomma 10W QI Wireless Fast Charger Car Mount Holder - 2pcs (it)";  

     $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' and post_status='publish'",$title1);

     $post_if = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

any help appreciated!

> Edit:

**Well i had to save the text from $title1=get_the_title(); to .txt file and i noticed that the – saved as `&#8211;` in the txt file ...then i replaced str_replace("`&#8211;`","-","Holder – 2pcs") and it works! the problem is that in my wordpress databse the title contains - char as it should but then when i use get_the_title(); function of wordpress in my code to retrieve the title i get the - char as – which is eventually `&#8211;` i dont know why get_the_title(); causing this issue! any thoughts?**

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! Just stating facts and asking for "any help" unfortunately makes this a too broad question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you escape that query incorrectly... You should use `esc_like` on the like part and `prepare` should be used a little bit different:

```
$title1 = 'Gocomma 10W QI Wireless Fast Charger Car Mount Holder - 2pcs (it)';
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
           "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title LIKE %s AND post_status = 'publish'",
           '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($title1) . '%'
       );
$post_if = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

But there is one more problem with this approach. There is a chance that the `-` character gets converted in some other character (like `—` - dash) and so on.

Comment: nope not working! i tried it. i think that the $title1=get_the_title(); which i use to give $title1 its value, is not assigned really as string. if i manually write the title it works! what might be wrong!

Comment: got it. its what you said " There is a chance that the - character gets converted in some other character (like — - dash) and so on. " - but how should i overcome it correctly?

Comment: @stefanosn put the correct character in your PHP string

Comment: i use str_replace("–","-",$title1); but not working! wtf!

Comment: Well i had to save the text from $title1=get_the_title(); to  .txt file and i noticed that the – saved as &#8211; in the txt file ...then i replaced str_replace("&#8211;","-","Holder – 2pcs") and it works! the problem is that in my wordpress databse the title contains - char as it should but then when i use get_the_title(); function of wordpress in my code to retrieve the title i get the - char as – which is eventually &#8211; i dont know why get_the_title(); causing this issue! any thoughts?